# Rankdir ignored when drawing

Tags: graphviz, rank, subgraph

I am trying to make the following digraph face a different direction, from top to bottom, instead of left to right. I have placed rankdir=tb and rank=same for the nodes I would like to be together, but I cannot get the wanted result (which you can see [here](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=strict%20digraph%20%22%22%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graph%20%5Boverlap%3Dfalse%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rankdir%3Dtb%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ranksep%3D.1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20splines%3Dortho%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5CN%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graph%20%5Brank%3Dsame%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20computerVisionPipeline%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dsalmon%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%221.computerVisionPipeline%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%221.computerVisionPipeline%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.focalDepthsComputation%22%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%222.focalDepthsComputation%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%222.focalDepthsComputation%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20computerVisionPipeline%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.focalDepthsComputation%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiStackDepthsSelection%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%223.multiStackDepthsSelection%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%223.multiStackDepthsSelection%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.focalDepthsComputation%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiStackDepthsSelection%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthSourcesProcessing%22%20%20%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%224.multiDepthSourcesProcessing%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%224.multiDepthSourcesProcessing%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiStackDepthsSelection%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthSourcesProcessing%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth%22%20%20%20%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dsalmon%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%225.multiDepth%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%225.multiDepth%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthSourcesProcessing%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthAggregation%22%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%228.multiDepthAggregation%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%228.multiDepthAggregation%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthAggregation%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.cellDetection%22%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%229.cellDetection%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%229.cellDetection%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthAggregation%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.cellDetection%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.cellSelection%22%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%2210.cellSelection%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%2210.cellSelection%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.cellDetection%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.cellSelection%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.featuresExtraction%22%20%20%20%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%2211.featuresExtraction%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%2211.featuresExtraction%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.cellSelection%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.featuresExtraction%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.featuresSaving%22%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%2212.featuresSaving%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%2212.featuresSaving%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.featuresExtraction%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.featuresSaving%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graph%20%5Brank%3Dsame%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%226.reconstruction%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%226.reconstruction%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.normalization%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%227.normalization%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%227.normalization%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.normalization%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction%22%3B%0D%0A%7D)). Does anyone know why this is happening? The source is directly provided from pygraphviz.

```
strict digraph "" {
        graph [overlap=false,
                rankdir=tb,
                ranksep=.1,
                splines=ortho
        ];
        node [label="\N"];
        {
                graph [rank=same];
                computerVisionPipeline  [color=black,
                        fillcolor=salmon,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="1.computerVisionPipeline",
                        name="1.computerVisionPipeline",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.focalDepthsComputation" [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="2.focalDepthsComputation",
                        name="2.focalDepthsComputation",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                computerVisionPipeline -> "computerVisionPipeline.focalDepthsComputation";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiStackDepthsSelection"      [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="3.multiStackDepthsSelection",
                        name="3.multiStackDepthsSelection",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.focalDepthsComputation" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiStackDepthsSelection";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthSourcesProcessing"    [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="4.multiDepthSourcesProcessing",
                        name="4.multiDepthSourcesProcessing",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiStackDepthsSelection" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthSourcesProcessing";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth"     [color=black,
                        fillcolor=salmon,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="5.multiDepth",
                        name="5.multiDepth",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthSourcesProcessing" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthAggregation"  [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="8.multiDepthAggregation",
                        name="8.multiDepthAggregation",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthAggregation";
                "computerVisionPipeline.cellDetection"  [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="9.cellDetection",
                        name="9.cellDetection",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthAggregation" -> "computerVisionPipeline.cellDetection";
                "computerVisionPipeline.cellSelection"  [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="10.cellSelection",
                        name="10.cellSelection",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.cellDetection" -> "computerVisionPipeline.cellSelection";
                "computerVisionPipeline.featuresExtraction"     [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="11.featuresExtraction",
                        name="11.featuresExtraction",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.cellSelection" -> "computerVisionPipeline.featuresExtraction";
                "computerVisionPipeline.featuresSaving" [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="12.featuresSaving",
                        name="12.featuresSaving",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.featuresExtraction" -> "computerVisionPipeline.featuresSaving";
        }
        {
                graph [rank=same];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction"      [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="6.reconstruction",
                        name="6.reconstruction",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.normalization"       [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="7.normalization",
                        name="7.normalization",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.normalization";
        }
        "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction";
}
```

Comment: rank=same means "put all these nodes on the same rank" (all on the same row in this case).  Try rankdir=LR

Comment: Thanks for the comment, indeed, but this does not have the desired effect, I want all the same ranked nodes to be on the same vertical level...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show what the desired graph should look like, from your description I do not understand well, I can assume that this is it:
[image: top bottom graph made with graphviz dot]
The way I achieved it was this:

- I removed `rankdir=tb,` because `dot` engine by default is top-down.
- I removed all `graph [rank=same];` but for vertical leveling I used [`group`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/group/) attribute, I added two groups `g1` and `g2` for separate graph to two vertical columns.
- I changed `ranksep` to `2` to add a little more length to the edges.

[Online editor](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=strict%20digraph%20%22%22%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graph%20%5Boverlap%3Dfalse%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ranksep%3D.2%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20splines%3Dortho%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5CN%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20computerVisionPipeline%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dsalmon%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%221.computerVisionPipeline%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%221.computerVisionPipeline%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.focalDepthsComputation%22%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%222.focalDepthsComputation%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%222.focalDepthsComputation%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20computerVisionPipeline%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.focalDepthsComputation%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiStackDepthsSelection%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%223.multiStackDepthsSelection%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%223.multiStackDepthsSelection%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.focalDepthsComputation%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiStackDepthsSelection%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthSourcesProcessing%22%20%20%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%224.multiDepthSourcesProcessing%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%224.multiDepthSourcesProcessing%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiStackDepthsSelection%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthSourcesProcessing%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth%22%20%20%20%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%20%20group%3Dg1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dsalmon%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%225.multiDepth%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%225.multiDepth%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthSourcesProcessing%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthAggregation%22%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%20group%3Dg1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%228.multiDepthAggregation%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%228.multiDepthAggregation%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthAggregation%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.cellDetection%22%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%229.cellDetection%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%229.cellDetection%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthAggregation%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.cellDetection%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.cellSelection%22%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%2210.cellSelection%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%2210.cellSelection%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.cellDetection%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.cellSelection%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.featuresExtraction%22%20%20%20%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%2211.featuresExtraction%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%2211.featuresExtraction%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.cellSelection%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.featuresExtraction%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.featuresSaving%22%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%2212.featuresSaving%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%2212.featuresSaving%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.featuresExtraction%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.featuresSaving%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%20group%3Dg2%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%226.reconstruction%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%226.reconstruction%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.normalization%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bcolor%3Dblack%2C%20group%3Dg2%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3Dlightblue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3Dblack%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3D%22verdana%20bold%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D14%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%227.normalization%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3D%227.normalization%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.normalization%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth%22%20-%3E%20%22computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction%22%3B%0D%0A%7D)
Script:

```
strict digraph "" {
        graph [overlap=false,
                ranksep=.2,
                splines=ortho
        ];
        node [label="\N"];
        {
                computerVisionPipeline  [color=black,
                        fillcolor=salmon,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="1.computerVisionPipeline",
                        name="1.computerVisionPipeline",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.focalDepthsComputation" [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="2.focalDepthsComputation",
                        name="2.focalDepthsComputation",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                computerVisionPipeline -> "computerVisionPipeline.focalDepthsComputation";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiStackDepthsSelection"      [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="3.multiStackDepthsSelection",
                        name="3.multiStackDepthsSelection",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.focalDepthsComputation" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiStackDepthsSelection";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthSourcesProcessing"    [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="4.multiDepthSourcesProcessing",
                        name="4.multiDepthSourcesProcessing",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiStackDepthsSelection" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthSourcesProcessing";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth"     [color=black,  group=g1,
                        fillcolor=salmon,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="5.multiDepth",
                        name="5.multiDepth",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthSourcesProcessing" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthAggregation"  [color=black, group=g1,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="8.multiDepthAggregation",
                        name="8.multiDepthAggregation",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthAggregation";
                "computerVisionPipeline.cellDetection"  [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="9.cellDetection",
                        name="9.cellDetection",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthAggregation" -> "computerVisionPipeline.cellDetection";
                "computerVisionPipeline.cellSelection"  [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="10.cellSelection",
                        name="10.cellSelection",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.cellDetection" -> "computerVisionPipeline.cellSelection";
                "computerVisionPipeline.featuresExtraction"     [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="11.featuresExtraction",
                        name="11.featuresExtraction",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.cellSelection" -> "computerVisionPipeline.featuresExtraction";
                "computerVisionPipeline.featuresSaving" [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="12.featuresSaving",
                        name="12.featuresSaving",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.featuresExtraction" -> "computerVisionPipeline.featuresSaving";
        }
        {
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction"      [color=black, group=g2,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="6.reconstruction",
                        name="6.reconstruction",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.normalization"       [color=black, group=g2,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="7.normalization",
                        name="7.normalization",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.normalization";
        }
        "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction";
}
```

### Variant №2 (horizontal branch)

Since the graph is located from top to bottom, you can give nodes the same rank (`{rank=same; node1; node2; ...; nodeN}`) for the horizontal arrangement.

**Variant for partially horizontal branch**, need to specify that the two nodes (`"computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction"`,`"computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.normalization"`) have the same rank. To do this, add the following lines:

```
...
        {       
                rank=same;
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.normalization";
        }
}
```

Image:
[image: vertical graph with partially horizontal branch made with graphviz dot]
Script:

```
strict digraph "" {
        graph [overlap=false,
                ranksep=.2,
                splines=ortho
        ];
        node [label="\N"];
        {
                computerVisionPipeline  [color=black,
                        fillcolor=salmon,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="1.computerVisionPipeline",
                        name="1.computerVisionPipeline",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.focalDepthsComputation" [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="2.focalDepthsComputation",
                        name="2.focalDepthsComputation",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                computerVisionPipeline -> "computerVisionPipeline.focalDepthsComputation";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiStackDepthsSelection"      [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="3.multiStackDepthsSelection",
                        name="3.multiStackDepthsSelection",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.focalDepthsComputation" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiStackDepthsSelection";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthSourcesProcessing"    [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="4.multiDepthSourcesProcessing",
                        name="4.multiDepthSourcesProcessing",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiStackDepthsSelection" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthSourcesProcessing";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth"     [color=black,  group=g1,
                        fillcolor=salmon,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="5.multiDepth",
                        name="5.multiDepth",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthSourcesProcessing" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthAggregation"  [color=black, group=g1,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="8.multiDepthAggregation",
                        name="8.multiDepthAggregation",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthAggregation";
                "computerVisionPipeline.cellDetection"  [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="9.cellDetection",
                        name="9.cellDetection",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepthAggregation" -> "computerVisionPipeline.cellDetection";
                "computerVisionPipeline.cellSelection"  [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="10.cellSelection",
                        name="10.cellSelection",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.cellDetection" -> "computerVisionPipeline.cellSelection";
                "computerVisionPipeline.featuresExtraction"     [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="11.featuresExtraction",
                        name="11.featuresExtraction",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.cellSelection" -> "computerVisionPipeline.featuresExtraction";
                "computerVisionPipeline.featuresSaving" [color=black,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="12.featuresSaving",
                        name="12.featuresSaving",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.featuresExtraction" -> "computerVisionPipeline.featuresSaving";
        }
        {
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction"      [color=black, group=g2,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="6.reconstruction",
                        name="6.reconstruction",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.normalization"       [color=black, group=g2,
                        fillcolor=lightblue,
                        fontcolor=black,
                        fontname="verdana bold",
                        fontsize=14,
                        label="7.normalization",
                        name="7.normalization",
                        shape=box,
                        style=filled];
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.normalization";
        }
        "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction";
        {       
                rank=same;
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.normalization";
        }
}
```

**Variant with full horizontal branch**, need to specify that the three nodes (`"computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth"`,`"computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction"`,`"computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.normalization"`) have the same rank. You can also adjust the edge length with the [`minlen`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/minlen/) attribute.
Image:
[image: vertical graph with full horizontal branch made with graphviz dot]
and changed part of code from the previous example:

```
...
        "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth" -> "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction" [minlen=4];
        {       
                rank=same;
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.reconstruction";
                "computerVisionPipeline.multiDepth.normalization";
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. The only issue I find is that I want the branch to be perpendicular to the root, or horizontal to the global view frame. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: @VasilisLemonidis, I added the second variant of the graph in my answer.